# Sorting Low Search results across multiple channels

Tags: low-search, sort, orderby

We've got two channel, Images and Videos, that we're combining in search results. Searching by keyword works great. So does sorting by entry_date and title. But we'd also like to sort by other fields.

To simplify things, imagine a custom field in each channel - video_score, image_score - that hold integers received from elsewhere. So, how would it be possible to combine these two for the orderby?

If it's easier we can create fields video_order and image_order with unique ordering numbers, but due to the custom fields being in two channels I don't see how to use the same custom field name, which appears to be what we need for orderby.

Do we maybe need to hijack a core field?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to create a custom extension that uses [the low_search_post_search hook](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/hooks#low_search_post_search). That will give you an array containing all parameters that will be passed through to the native channel:entries tag for parsing the results. That includes the entry_id or fixed_order parameter which contains the entry IDs for the search results (as long as [a LS filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters) has been triggered).

With that list of IDs, you can query the DB for the values you want to sort by, and then re-sort the entry IDs based on those values. If you then set the fixed_order param with the newly sorted list, the search results should appear in the desired order.

Another way would be to create a fieldtype that hijacks a core field (as you suggested) [like view_count_one to four](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/entry_tracking.html).